# VBA if another cell "MAINTENANCE" then return "CLOSED", otherwise leave cell empty for user to input text

Tags: excel, vba

So I am creating a worksheet that requires a cell to return the text "CLOSED" if another cell has text "MAINTENANCE". At first glance I tried using

```
=if(A2 = "MAINTENANCE", "CLOSED", "")
```

...and so on for every other row.

However, if I need to input text, I would have to erase the function first, it is not a big deal to do so, but I was just curious if there was a VBA way to do it without having to delete anything.

Example Below:

[image: EXAMPLE:]

Notice that every row that has "Maintenance" on column C, it autofills as "CLOSED" on the column B, and if column C is anything other than "MAINTENANCE", it leaves the column B blank for me to type.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A cell can either contain a value, or a formula.  Even using VBA, you can't have both.  Instead of using a formula, you could use the `worksheet_change` event to trigger placing "CLOSED" in colA when a row in ColB is updated to "MAINTENANCE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Save the change event code into worksheet module

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 And .Column = 3 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If StrComp(.Value, "MAINTENANCE", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                .Offset(0, -1).Value = "CLOSED"
            Else
                .Offset(0, -1).Value = ""
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When you say "save the change event code into worksheet module", do you mean double-click on the left pane where it says "Sheet1 (NAME OF SHEET)" and then paste your code on the right side?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Save the file as *.xlsm or *.xlsb.

Comment: I did as you instructed, copy pasted the code into the worksheet module, saved as XLSM and also tried as XLSB but nothing is happening, is the code supposed to run automatically by just placing it where you indicated? sorry in advance if it is a dumb question

Comment: It's a typo in my code. Please try again with `.Column = 3`.

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change: Flag If Match

[image]

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const FIRST_CHANGE_CELL As String = "C2"
    Const CHANGE_STRING As String = "MAINTENANCE"
    Const RETURN_COLUMN As String = "B"
    Const RETURN_STRING As String = "CLOSED"
    Const MATCH_CASE As Boolean = False
    
    ' Reference the Change (single-column) range ('crg' i.e. 'C2:C1048576').
    Dim crg As Range
    With Me.Range(FIRST_CHANGE_CELL)
        Set crg = .Resize(Me.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    ' Reference the changed cells ('icrg') of the Change range.
    Dim icrg As Range: Set icrg = Intersect(crg, Target)
    If icrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim cOffset As Long:
    cOffset = Me.Columns(RETURN_COLUMN).Column - crg.Column
    Dim MatchCase As VbCompareMethod: MatchCase = MATCH_CASE + 1
    
    ' Combine each matching cell ('rcell') into a range union ('curg')
    ' and each not matching cell ('rcell') into another range union ('rurg').
    
    Dim curg As Range, ccell As Range, rurg As Range, rCell As Range
    
    For Each ccell In icrg.Cells
        Set rCell = ccell.Offset(, cOffset)
        If StrComp(CStr(ccell.Value), CHANGE_STRING, MatchCase) = 0 Then
            If StrComp(CStr(rCell.Value), RETURN_STRING, MatchCase) <> 0 Then
                BuildRange curg, rCell
            End If
        Else
            If StrComp(CStr(rCell.Value), RETURN_STRING, MatchCase) = 0 Then
                BuildRange rurg, rCell
            End If
        End If
    Next ccell
    
    ' Write.
    Application.EnableEvents = False ' prevent endless loop (when writing)
        ' Write return string to matching cells of return column.
        If Not curg Is Nothing Then curg.Value = RETURN_STRING
        ' Clear return string from not matching cells of return column.
        If Not rurg Is Nothing Then rurg.ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1` (optionally in the same sheet module)**

```vb
Function BuildRange( _
    ByRef rgBuilt As Range, _
    ByVal rgAdd As Range) _
As Range
    If rgBuilt Is Nothing Then
        Set rgBuilt = rgAdd
    Else
        Set rgBuilt = Union(rgBuilt, rgAdd)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: It seems like you really put an effort there, however, my coding skills are no where near to be able to understand what the above is supposed to do :s

Comment: That shouldn't prevent you from testing the code. Copy it to the correct sheet module of a new workbook and start entering values or copying single or multiple cells in columns B and C to figure out its functionality.